# Python classes to grab HTTP response from website entities

Tags: python, object-oriented, web-scraping, http, authentication

I am trying to implement a parent `WebContent` class and child classes to grab HTTP responses from the actual website entities. There are highlevel codes below and I am wondering what are people's perspectives in terms of the neatest way to implement this in a OOP manner.

```
import requests
from onelogin.api.client import OneLoginClient


class WebContent(object):

    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, login, password, sub_domain, app_id, app_url):

        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.app_id = app_id
        self.app_url = app_url
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        self.sub_domain = sub_domain

    def _login(self):
        client = OneLoginClient(self.client_id, self.client_secret)
        saml = client.get_saml_assertion(self.login,
                                         self.password,
                                         self.app_id,
                                         self.sub_domain)
        saml_data = saml.saml_response

        session = requests.Session()
        saml_payload = {'SAMLResponse': saml_data}
        session.post("{}/sso/response".format(self.app_url), saml_payload)
        return session

    def get_content(self, endpoint, time_out=30):
        if endpoint:
            session = self._login()
            result = session.get(endpoint, timeout=time_out)
            session.close()
            return result.content


class WebMarketingContent(WebContent):
    def get_endpoint(self, entity_id):
        base_url = "{app_url}/{entity_id}?{query_params}"
        params = '&entity_id={}'.format(entity_id)
        return base_url.format(app_url=self.app_url, query_params=params)


class WebEducationContent(WebContent):
    def get_endpoint(self, entity_id):
        base_url = "{app_url}/category/adhoc_element/{entity_id}?{query_params}"
        params = '&entity_id={}'.format(entity_id)
        return base_url.format(app_url=self.app_url, query_params=params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    web_marketing_content = WebMarketingContent('client_id',
                                                'client_secret',
                                                'email',
                                                'password',
                                                'sub_domain',
                                                'app_id',
                                                'app_url')

    endpoint = web_marketing_content.get_endpoint(123)
    result = web_marketing_content.get_content(endpoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. `if __name__ == '__main__':` is usually followed by a call to a `main` method. The `main` method then parses arguments using for example [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to inject all the things which should not be hardcoded in the application - definitely passwords, but in your case probably all of the parameters to `WebMarketingContent`. This makes the code reusable and scriptable.
2. `WebEducationContent` is not used anywhere, so it should be removed.
3. Take advantage of static analysis and formatting using `black`, `flake8` and `mypy` with a strict configuration to improve the overall quality.
4. You shouldn't need to get the endpoint before getting the content. `web_marketing_content.get_content(123)` should itself work out the endpoint and request it.